# Is it possible to iterate the next element in single iteration using for-each loop and How?

Tags: java, arrays

I started replacing the for loop by for-each loop but i don't know whether can we replace the below scenario by for-each loop.

Sample code :

```
String[] names = {"", ""};
for(int i =0; i<names.length - 1; i++) {
    if(names[i].equals(names[i+1]))
        break;
}
```

Using for-each loop, we can iterate one element at a time like

```
for(String name : names){
    System.out.println(name);
}
```

can anyone, please help me.
Thanks.

Updated :

Looking for generalized solution for below code snippet :

```
boolean flag = false;
    for(int i=0; i<names.length-1; i++) {
        // logic
        for(int j=i+1; j<names.length; j++) {
            if(names[i].equalsIgnoreCase(names[j])) {
                flag = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(flag){
            break;
        }
    }
```

is it possible to replace above for loop by Enhanced for-loop?.

Comment: You cannot compare string with `==` operator, use `.equals()`

Comment: You can compare them, it being wise is a different case. What the OP wants is not possible I'm afraid, you'll have to stick with the indexed for loop. Or keep track of an index yourself with the enhanced for loop.

Comment: @freedev sure you can (and in some cases, it even makes sense). It's just that it usually doesn't give the results you want :D

Comment: @freedev, you are write, what i mentioned above code is an sample code, that's not an actual code.

Comment: @Koekje, How to keep index track using enhanced for loop, please can you add more details on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```
String lastName = null;
for (String name : names) {
  if (name.equals(lastName))
    break;
  lastName = name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Iterator iter = Arrays.asList(names).iterator();
iter.next();
for(String name:names) {
    if(iter.hasNext()&&name.equals(iter.next()))
    {
        System.out.println(name);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer, just posting a code snippet is not appropriate.

Comment: @bureaquete sure but looked like its self explanatory. Just have to iterable and use them to achieve what is being asked for